# Access height of a \parbox

Tags: boxes, lengths, parbox

Within a `\parbox`  I can access its width via `\linewidth` (useful e.g. if I want to place an image as wide as the `\parbox`). Is there a way of accessing the height of a `\parbox` *when the height is fixed by the optional argument*? (Of course the question makes sense only in this case.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\fbox{\parbox{100pt}{Some text, some more text, and \the\linewidth}}

% here I'd like something like \parboxheight or similar
\fbox{\parbox[][100pt][t]{100pt}{Some text, some more text, and \the\linewidth, and the height?}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ht` can be used.

Comment: I don't think so, if I got it right then parbox first puts everything in a box and then unbox this in a box of the requested height. The height argument isn't stored anywhere before the first box is created. So you would have to patch the command or write your own wrapper.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oops, I missed the unboxing bit. So `@parboxto` will not be useful, then. But another solution might involve doing `\let\Lparbox=\parbox` and then making a new command `\parbox` which squirrels away the height argument, if present, and then invokes `\Lparbox`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution patches `\@iiiparbox` to get the height in the second parameter. The value is stored in the dimension register `\parboxheight`.

If the height is not set, LaTeX uses `\relax` for this parameter.
Then, `\parboxheight` is set to zero. If you want to know, whether the
height parameter was set the optional argument, an additional switch
can be used.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\parboxheight

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@iiiparbox}{}
\let\org@iiiparbox\@iiiparbox
\renewcommand*{\@iiiparbox}[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2%
    \setlength{\parboxheight}{0pt}%
  \else
    \setlength{\parboxheight}{#2}%
  \fi
  \org@iiiparbox{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\fbox{\parbox{100pt}{Some text, some more text, and \the\linewidth}}

\fbox{%
  \parbox[][80pt][t]{100pt}{%
    \raggedright
    Some text, some more text, and width \the\linewidth, %
    and the height \the\parboxheight.%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With switch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifparboxheight
\newdimen\parboxheight

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@iiiparbox}{}
\let\org@iiiparbox\@iiiparbox
\renewcommand*{\@iiiparbox}[2]{%
  \ifx\relax#2%
    \parboxheightfalse
    \setlength{\parboxheight}{0pt}%
  \else
    \parboxheighttrue
    \setlength{\parboxheight}{#2}%
  \fi
  \org@iiiparbox{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\newcommand*{\TestText}{%
  \raggedright
  Some text, some more text. The width is \the\linewidth
  \ifparboxheight
    \ and the height is \the\parboxheight
  \fi
  .%
}

\fbox{\parbox{100pt}{\TestText}}

\fbox{\parbox[][80pt][t]{100pt}{\TestText}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with switch]

Answer (score 4):

The dimension is in argument `#2` to `\@iiiparbox`, so we can patch `\parbox` in order to save the argument in a length register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\parboxtodim}
\patchcmd{\@iiiparbox}
  {\hsize}
  {\ifx\relax#2\else\setlength{\parboxtodim}{#2}\fi\hsize}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\fbox{\parbox{100pt}{Some text, some more text, and \the\linewidth}}

% here I'd like something like \parboxheight or similar
\fbox{\parbox[][200pt][t]{100pt}{%
  Some text, some more text, and \the\linewidth, and \the\parboxtodim
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newbox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\parbox{100pt}{This is a test.}}
\begin{document}
\the\ht\mybox\ and \the\wd\mybox
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: He wanted access to the declared height *from within the parbox itself*. So this doesn't answer the question. Admittedly, you had to read between the lines a bit to get that.