# Equal size underbraces at a lower position

Tags: math-mode, markdown, underbrace

I am writing a markdown document and I want to have underbraces of equal size under each term, like the one here:

[image]

I could only do it manually by adding a bunch of empty spaces (`\` ) around the terms:

```
$$
\underbrace{\ \ \ \ X_t \ \ \ \ }_\text{Population at time $t$} =
\underbrace{\alpha \circ X_{t-1}}_\text{Survivors from time $t-1$} +
\underbrace{\ \ \ \ \epsilon_t \ \ \ \ }_\text{Immigration} 
$$
```

Though, it is not efficient to add spaces manually (and investigating visually whether they end up of equal size), and they do not look nice and need to be lowered a bit.:

[image]

How can I fix it?

(Please ignore the mismatch of the circle operators; I have posted it [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580581/166234).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) can help with this via it's `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` macro. All `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` is set in a box that is of maximum width. Additional `<align>`ment can be specified (`l`eft, `c`entre or `r`ight) on a per-use basis. Not sure whether this will work in Markdown, as it requires at least two compilations with any change in the maximum width of elements using the same `<tag>`.

I've added `\eqmathbox` that translates the definition into a math-friendly environment (since there are different styles of display within math mode). If you don't have an up-to-date LaTeX, you should also include [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) (...or update your LaTeX distribution).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse}% If you have LaTeX2e < 2020-10-01

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
% \eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<math>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{\vphantom{\Big|} #3} % \vphantom{\Big|} added to push the braces lower
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \underbrace{\eqmathbox[Xt]{          X_t         }}_\text{Population at time $t$} =
    \underbrace{\eqmathbox[Xt]{\alpha \circ X_{t - 1}}}_\text{Survivors from time $t - 1$} +
    \underbrace{\eqmathbox[Xt]{      \epsilon_t      }}_\text{Immigration} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation! How can I lower the underbraces, other than adding `\vphantom{\Big|}`, as @SebGlav suggested above?

Comment: You can access the `\parbox` height but it's a bit trickier. Follow this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387074/access-height-of-a-parbox

Comment: @ManuHaq: You can add it (a strut, like `\vphantom{\Big|}` to the definition of `\eqmathbox` to hide it from your readable code.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am going to edit that and accept this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You use a `\parbox`-based approach along the following lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional - Times Roman text and math fonts
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle\alpha\circ X_{t-1}$} % measure width of widest element
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{\centering$\displaystyle #1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\mybox{X_t}}_{\text{Population at time $t$}} =
\underbrace{\mybox{\alpha\circ X_{t-1}}}_{\text{Survivors from time $t-1$}} +
\underbrace{\mybox{P\epsilon_t}}_{\text{Immigration}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever, and way better than my solution ;)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a more general/straightforward solution that can be applied elsewhere, without having to specifically setting $\mylen$? Imagine somewhere else I have another equation with a wider term.

Comment: @ManuHaq - I'm afraid you need to be a bit more specific as to what it is you wish to achieve. The example above uses one `\settowidth` instruction because there's just one equation; if there are two equations in the document, you can just run a second `\settowidth` instruction. Observe that it would not be necessary to redefine the `\mybox` macro. If you're averse to measuring the width of the widest element to be under-braced directly, you're entirely free to choose some arbitrary length that's as least as large as `\mylen`.

Comment: I found this solution the better, and it's very understandable. It computes the length of the biggest brace and adjusts the others accordingly. I can't see anything more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

One very ugly way to do it is to cheat with some `\vphantom`. Please note that you can also insert horizontal spaces with `\hspace*` instead of a series of backslashes. There is probably a better way to achieve all this but, for a start...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$
\underbrace{\vphantom{\Big|} \hspace*{5mm} X_t \hspace*{5mm}}_\text{Population at time $t$} =
\underbrace{\vphantom{\Big|}\alpha \circ X_{t-1}}_\text{Survivors from time $t-1$} +
\underbrace{\vphantom{\Big|} \hspace*{5mm} \epsilon_t \hspace*{5mm}}_\text{Immigration} 
$$

\end{document}
```

[image: underbraces]

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\ubrace` macro and use `\def\ubracew{max-width-formula}` before each such formula inside math mode.

```
\def\ubrace#1#2{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle\ubracew$}%
   \underbrace{\hbox to\wd0{\hss$\displaystyle#1$\lower.8ex\hbox{}\hss}}%
   _{\text{#2}}%
}

$$
\def\ubracew{\alpha\circ X_{t-1}}
\ubrace{X_t}{Population at time $t$} =
\ubrace{\alpha \circ X_{t-1}}{Survivors from time $t-1$} +
\ubrace{\epsilon_t}{Immigration}
$$
```